# Re-Track Current Tune in Main Library Panel

Tags: 11.04, banshee

After clicking away from the library panel view, where Banshee tracks the current tune, is there a way to reactivate?  In iTunes there is a specific button for this.  Banshee will always show the current tune playing, but I cannot seem to get the library view to synch again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking to jump back to the currently playing song, you can do this with the shortcut Ctrl-J or the menu item Playback > Jump to Playing Song.

Is this what you're looking for?